# Accessing the blocks of storage using c program

Tags: filesystems, storage, block

I need to access data of a storage directly. I want to read/write a chunk of data from the storage providing the offset and length of the data.
Please suggest a way or provide some c code to access the block of storage(not file)

I'll also be happy if someone guides me to do this job done using the customized file system.

Comment: if you don't want to use files,  what do you want to use?

Comment: Actually if I use file, then each block of file should be mapped into storage in separate place of storage. I want to use SSD and access blocks of SSD using different channel of SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can map a portion of a file into memory with the `mmap(2)` system call. This is taken from the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
           int fd, off_t offset);
int munmap(void *addr, size_t length);
```

> mmap() creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process.  The starting address for the new mapping is specified in `addr`.  The `length` argument specifies the length of the mapping.